# ERROR UPDATING THE SQLITE DATABASE IN ANDROID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have to update the details in a table named CLERK, using this code:

```
try
{
    //update query

    myDataBase.execSQL("UPDATE CLERK SET" +
        " CLK_NAME='" + sql_clk_name + "'," +
        " CLK_EXPIRY_DATE='" + sql_expirydt + "'," +
        " CLK_PASSWORD='" + sql_password + "'" +
        " WHERE CLK_ID = '" + sql_clk_id + "'" , null);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MODIFIED !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "error modifying clerk",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When I run it, I get an exception, `ex=null`. The record is definitely present in the db.

When I use `"cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery"` instead of `"myDataBase.execSQL"` the query execute but not reflected in the database.. someone help me out please

Comment: there is no null in the variables that i am passing such as clk_name,clk_expiry_date,clk_password,clk_id....

Comment: also add  logcat result with question

Comment: doesn't seem to be working even if i hard code the update query

Comment: is your CLK_ID define as string in the table.

Comment: the query is working well its the rest of the code that i have somewhere made a mistake in

Comment: Did you pass a context to your database class? If yes, why not use it instead of getApplicationContext().

Comment: The only code beside execSQL is the Toast before the catch. Remove the toast and see if you still get exception.

Comment: it exceptions out before the toast. i checked t by commenting the toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your effort and time. how ever i have found a way to update.

this is how...

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("CLK_NAME", sql_clk_name);
values.put("CLK_EXPIRY_DATE", sql_expirydt);
values.put("CLK_PASSWORD", sql_password);myDataBase.update("CLERK",values,"CLK_ID='" +    sql_clk_id + "'",null);
```

and it has worked like wonders :)